# Rails - Different form_for statements for the same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, code-duplication

I'm trying to avoid code duplication between Admin forms and Regular User forms for the same resource.

I would like to be able to use one form for both, by doing something like:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
  <%= form_for([:admin,@post], :html => {class: "form"}) do |f| %>
<% else %>
  <%= form_for @post, html: { class: 'form' } do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

then include fields that only the admin should see via if statements in the body of the form.

This approach doesn't work, I think because the <% end %> is ending the form.

Is there a way to do this?  Does this approach even make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it will work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to move the code to your helper may help:

```
#YourHelper.rb
def form_for_admin(condition, &block)
    if condition
        form_for [:admin, @post], :html => {class: "form"}, &block
    else
        form_for @post, html: { class: 'form' }, &block
    end
end
```

and use:

```
<%= form_for_admin current_user.admin? do |f| %>
```

Comment: This solution worked great.  However, I ended up realizing that while I wanted to avoid duplication, I did not want the admins to see different forms than the user on the front end of the application.  I ended up just abstracting duplicate sections into partials and passing in the local f variable like:  <%= render partial: 'form_fields', locals: { f: f } %>